# Building assets under different paths with Rails and webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker

I am working on a Rails 5.2.3 application where I have application.js/.css as well as additional files organized into directories as follows:

In my layout I do this:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "#{controller_path}/action_name" if File.exist?(Rails.root.join("app/assets/javascripts", controller_path, action_name, ".js") ) %>
```

I have hundreds of JS and CSS files organized under directories 3-4 levels deep.

After going through the webpacker literature I am still not sure how I am supposed to set it up for this particular use case - it appears entry points must go under app/javascripts/packs but I'm not sure how this webpacker thing can help me at all, am I supposed to go into each view and add individual links to its JS?

How do I get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can organize your files in the `app/javascript` folder either under packs or in your own folder structure.
You can then either import into `app/javascript/packs/application.js` and call it with the `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application" %>`. 
Or, if you have files in the packs folder you can require single files directly in the view with the same rails helper but the respective file name so e.g `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'file_name" %>`.